# Proof of Funds for Canadian Visa

Tags: visas, canada, proof-of-funds, romanian-citizens

I am a Romanian citizen.  Our co-national friends who are established in Canada will provide me and another person free accommodation and food. We are both EU citizens and we will stay in Canada 1 month.

These days we are gathering documents for our online visa application and we need to prove that we have enough money to spend there.

**How much money is generally required in order to be sure we are eligible?** We don't plan to spend more than 1000 EUR, but I intend to bring at least 2000 CAD. Is it enough?

Comment: Did you look up your nationality on the [Canadian government website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp)? Many (most?) EU nationals don't need a visa to visit Canada as a tourist

Comment: Of course I did :) *Country: Romania
You need a visa to visit or transit Canada.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very much a matter of judgement on the part of the border officer. There is no magic number. I have seen (on Border Security) a person with $8 and no bank account allowed in because the people he was staying with assured the officer they would cover all his food and expenses while he stayed with them. I've seen an American coming in near Vancouver headed to Alaska with $1200 denied because he said he needed 10 days to get to Alaska and the officer felt that $120 a day was not enough and he was probably planning to work his way there since he hadn't brought enough money. (She also felt he was planning on spending too long to get there, which made it worse.)

I'm sure you know that $2000 wouldn't support two people in a hotel and eating at restaurants for a month. However if you're staying with friends, then $70 a day for restaurants, travelling around (eg subway fares), and getting into tourist attractions seems reasonable. If I were your border officer (and I'm not, right?) then I'd be fine with the amount of money you're planning to bring.

Answer (score -1):

As part of the process to be approved for a Canadian visa, you normally must be able to show that you have enough money to take care of yourself while you are living in Canada (plus meet the other eligibility criteria). In general, an individual foreign national may need to provide “proof of funds” in the amount of approximately $1,230 CAD per month, so if you plan to bring at least $2,000 CAD for this 30-day tourist visit, that should be adequate in terms of the Canadian visa application process (you may want to bring more money, depending on what you want to do in Canada). Evidence of your ability to support yourself during your visit to Canada may include cash, a bank statement or deposit book, written or verbal statements from your Canadian friends (that can be adequately verified) confirming they will provide your accommodations in Canada, or other satisfactory documentation.

Comment: Where did that magic number come from?