# Proof of funds for a UK citizen visiting Canada for 5 months

Tags: visas, canada, uk-citizens, proof-of-funds

I'm a little worried. My partner and I are planning to travel to Canada in less than a week, with return flights booked for just over a 5 months period. We've been told this will suffice for a tourist visa to accommodate for this period.

I'm not sure about proof of funds. I get paid 2 days after we arrive in Canada and my wage slip will be posted out to me too late. My partner's wages and my funds should come to about 4-5000CAD combined. We have a hotel booked for the first 5 nights as we have viewings scheduled for those days for our accommodation. We do have friends to visit and a further 3000CAD from my wages. I've seen posts on other sites about having proof of accommodation and funds.

What quantity of funds are needed and what will happen with regards to accommodation proof?

Comment: Welcome to the site, what exactly is your question ? Do you already have the visa ? Are you worried someone will inquire about accommodation and your funding ?

Comment: no we were originally going for an IEC but are on a waiting list like alot of people so we stayed a while longer in the UK to get the funds to live off wihtout work so we were planning on coming as a tourist, i am worried yes, that it will be a negative that we dont have pre-booked accommodation for the whole trip so no figures so how much it will cost, and that we dont know how much they will expect us to have as the IEC expect $2500 each but thats a year or two i think?

Comment: This may be useful reading for you http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47105/proof-of-funds-for-canadian-visa

Comment: You're still expected to show proof of funds even if you're staying with friends or family. If you are, they can definitely help by supplying you with proof of hosting to show the border agent. Perhaps your employers can do the same in advance of your pay

Answer (score 3):

I tried to find the information on Canada Border Services Agency' website but it was not very clear. Hence I'm answering this with my experience: CBSA is very strict but reasonable on these matters, in the end it'll be up to you convincing the agent you talk to that you are no longer intending to work in Canada, even if the opportunity arises, and that you can support yourselves or that you'll have means (like a flexible plane ticket) and intent (like a profound respect for Canadian immigration law and hopes to come back again in the future) to leave Canada if you run out of money.

They're very likely to inquire further when they see the combination of application but no IEC issued, long stay, and frankly very extremely low funds. The case is different from the IEC, as tourists you're expected to support yourselves without entering the Canadian labour market whereas IEC visitors can work to build up funds with which to travel. If you can only prove $4000 for two people, that's only $13 a day per person over five months. It's hard to do much and get by on that even eating peanut butter and crackers from Dollarama. If you can prove $8000 that's still only $27 per person per day, which is barely around the price of the cheapest hotels in all of Canada.

Primarily they'll be interested in you not working. Since you're staying for that long, having very good proof that you'll have a very low costs while visiting Canada (exact plans for accommodation with friends, camping, etc.) is key. It's possible they'll want to contact anyone who you say is providing you with free accommodation. They'll be extremely interested in the fact that you don't work, including working around the house in exchange for accommodation.