# Question: Funds available for my stay (CAD)

Tags: visas, canada, proof-provenance-of-funds

I was filling the application form for Canadian visitor visa. There was a field that asked me to tell the funds available for my stay in Canada.

1) Is it asking me to tell the total funds that I have in my bank etc? 
2) Or, is it asking me to tell the funds I am bringing to Canada for my stay?

Comment: Possible [duplicate of Proof of Funds](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47105/proof-of-funds-for-canadian-visa) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it asks about what funds are available, it means both what you will carry in cash, and what you can access through credit or debit cards or through your bank, should that be necessary. If your personal circumstances require sharing your bank statements, credit card limits, and other information as evidence that you can support yourself during your visit, you should include it with your application.